# Is there any virtue of synonym for Table or View over using a VIEW?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, synonym

For decades i've used `VIEW`s as a synonym:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Banks AS

SELECT *
FROM OtherDatabase.dbo.Banks
```

i do this so i can abstract where the *"real"* table is. And when it changes, it's as simple as altering the view:

And this works well. It's doesn't cause the optimizer any issues, and i have been able to edit the view as required.

[image]

## Synonyms

Starting with SQL Server 2005, Microsoft introduced synonyms:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Banks FOR OtherDatabase.dbo.Banks
```

It **seems** to work **identically** to the `VIEW` approach. Every execution plan i've looked at behaves identically.

Unfortunately it seems that synonyms are unable to provide [one of their basic functions, functionality i need](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx):

> Provides a layer of abstraction that protects a client application from changes made to the name or location of the base object

You are not able to change where a synonym points. Because there is no ALTER SYNONYM statement, you first have to drop the synonym and then re-create the synonym with the same name, but point the synonym to the new location.

## Do they have any redeeming quality?

Practically speaking, this isn't going to happen. i will just never do it. i won't use a mechanism that requires me to drop objects from a database in order to change a setting. i'm certainly not going to delete all the easily alterable **VIEWs**, replacing them with **SYNONYMs**, and have to explain to everyone why making everything harder is *"better"*.

So my question is, is there anything i am losing by using views?

- every execution plan looks identical to synonyms
- i can easily change the *"view synonym"* at any time

Is there a virtue to a table or view synonym that i'm missing?

> Aside from having to call `RefreshAllViews` in case i forgot that i made a table change somewhere

## Even stored procedures

i don't even use synonyms for stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetUSDNoonRateAsOf @tradeDate datetime AS

EXECUTE OtherDatabase.dbo.GetUSDNoonRateAsOf @tradeDate
```

Is there a value in synonyms that i am missing?

## Update: RefreshAllViews procedure

We have a standard procedure in every database. Reordering, or inserting, columns wreaks havoc on views; so they have to be *"refreshed"*.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RefreshAllViews] AS

-- This sp will refresh all views in the catalog. 
--     It enumerates all views, and runs sp_refreshview for each of them

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE abc CURSOR FOR
     SELECT TABLE_NAME AS ViewName
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
     ORDER BY newid()
OPEN abc

DECLARE @ViewName varchar(128)
--DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)

-- Build select string once 
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(2048)
--SET @SQLString = N'EXECUTE sp_RefreshView @View'
--SET @ParmDefinition = N'@View nvarchar(128)'

FETCH NEXT FROM abc 
INTO @ViewName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    IF @ViewName <> 'IndexServerNodes'
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLString = 'EXECUTE sp_RefreshView '+@ViewName
        PRINT @SQLString
        EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @SQLString--, @ParmDefinition, @View = @ViewName
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM abc
    INTO @ViewName
END
CLOSE abc
DEALLOCATE abc
```

*God knows why SQL Server doesn't do it for me.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A synonym is a much more transparent redirect. I prefer them over views because views need to be maintained. When you use `SELECT *` especially.

I'm not sure I buy that the lack of `ALTER SYNONYM` is a real blocker. The drop/create of a synonym is a very simple metadata operation, and will be very fast. Omitting error handling for brevity:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  DROP SYNONYM ...
  CREATE SYNONYM ...
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Similarly, for stored procedures, if your base stored procedure interface changes (say, you add a parameter), you have to also change the wrapper procedure - not so with a synonym.

One downside is that you can create, say, an instead of trigger on a view, but you can't on a synonym. There are other operations you can't perform via a synonym (mostly DDL). And of course [IntelliSense may not function correctly, depending on version](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/331633).

Not being able to memorize the syntax seems like a made-up excuse to me. [There are no fancy options or with clauses](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx); just a 2-part name for the synonym, and a 2-, 3- or 4-part name for the object it refers to:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Something FOR Server.Database.dbo.SomethingElse;
```

If you can't memorize that, how did you create the synonym in the first place?

I also have a suggestion to thoroughly simplify your stored procedure (and prevent it from failing when any view is not in the `dbo` schema, or the procedure is executed by someone whose default schema is not the same as the view's schema, or the view has an `'` or space in its name, or otherwise breaks any of the [rules for identifiers (you can find them on this page)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(v=sql.105).aspx)):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RefreshAllViews] 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

  SELECT @sql += '
    EXEC sp_refreshview ' + CHAR(39) 
    + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(s.name,'''','''''')) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(v.name,'''','''''')) + CHAR(39) + ';'
  FROM sys.views AS v
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON v.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id];

  PRINT @sql;
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

At the very least, if you're going to keep the cursor, [stop using the terrible default options (declare the cursor as `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD`)](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options), and [use `sys.views` instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

> *God knows why SQL Server doesn't do it for me.*

Because SQL Server is software, and [it isn't perfect - especially when it comes to dependencies](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008). The main problem is that you are violating a best practice by using [`SELECT *` in your views in the first place](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list). *shrug* If you would accept your hang-ups about synonyms, you won't have to worry about that.

Comment: The issue with the lack of ability to alter a synonym, is there is no way to alter them from the UI. i'm not going to rememberize the syntax. Only when i'm feeling 1337 do i write a `CREATE INDEX` by hand; and even then it takes me 2 or 3 tries to get right.

Comment: @Ian that is a very poor excuse IMHO. The syntax for `CREATE SYNONYM` is very simple compared to `CREATE INDEX`. `CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Something FOR SomeDatabase.dbo.SomethingElse;` - is that really hard?

Comment: @IanBoyd Being lazy is not a real reason not to use something.  I'm also willing to bet this puts you in a minority, since most serious SQL developers and DBAs script everything out for reproduce-ability. If I caught someone in my department using the GUI for everything I would be seriously pissed since A) it's unsafe and B) it takes a LOT longer to do.

Comment: @JNK good points, you also have a much tougher time storing deployment instructions that use a GUI in source control (you could take a video, I guess, and store that).

Comment: In the end i'm not going to use them. They don't seem to have any virtue, and only add headache.

Comment: @Ian what headache are you talking about?

Comment: @JNK 7 or 8 years ago i discovered the horrible dangers in scripting out database changes, and running them separately, in order to apply database updates. You only lose data once on a live server to not make that mistake again. You should never run change scripts generated by SSMS yourself.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The inability to change a synonym. i asked (out loud, to no one, to the universe) why can't i change this synonym. A co-worker asked why he can't change the synonym. i have the need to change a synonym. You cannot. Using a view as a synonym i can change it. And since there seems to be no performance or compilation benefit to using views, and i get to keep the flexibility of being able to modify the views, i'll continue to use views.

Comment: @IanBoyd I'm saying you WRITE the scripts and then you have re-runnable deployable code.

Comment: I completely agree. I never run change scripts generated by SSMS myself. I either use a generic account or wait until I find an unattended workstation so the change doesn't get traced back to me

Comment: @IanBoyd the gas tank on a Mercedes is on the right-hand side. I guess I won't buy a Mercedes because they won't make me one with a gas tank on the left-hand side. I sure hate pulling up to the gas pump and walking all the way around my car to pump gas. How often are you *changing* synonyms, seriously? You don't have to change them when you change a column (like you do with your views) *OR* when you change a parameter (like you do with your stored procedures). So why did you bother asking this question? I've shown why synonyms are better but you don't seem to care. Next time I won't bother.

Comment: @Aaron i was aware of those limitations (hence the `RefreshAllViews` procedure we use). i was wondering if there was anything else that would make synonyms attractive; rather than a detriment. Nor was i looking for someone to convince me to use them. i was looking for possible virtues that i missed. Either way, you got your upvoted and accepted reputation; be happy.

Comment: @Ian I don't give a crap about reputation etc., however I do care when people solve problems the wrong way or make invalid excuses for doing it the right way. My answer clearly explains why synonyms are better than the way you're doing it today. Your only excuse not to change is that you can't memorize `CREATE SYNONYM dbo.whatever FOR dbo.somethingelse;` for those rare occasions where you might need to change a synonym to point to a different object (unlike the much more common scenarios, such as changing columns or parameters, you have to deal with now). *shrug* I can't fix that.

Comment: You answered the question; you gave me exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

If a view references a table, and you subsequently add columns to that table, you must modify the view in order to “pick up” the new column—even if you use `SELECT *`. Synonyms will “pick up” those columns automatically. Here’s a sample script:

```
--  Set things up
CREATE TABLE Foo
 (
   Id   int          not null
  ,data varchar(10)  not null
 )
GO

INSERT Foo values (1,'one'),(2,'Two')
GO


CREATE SYNONYM synFoo for Foo
GO


CREATE VIEW vFooDelim as select Id, Data from Foo
GO

CREATE VIEW vFooStar as select * from Foo
GO

select * from Foo
select * from synFoo
select * from vFooDelim
select * from vFooStar
```

then,

```
--  Add a column
ALTER TABLE Foo
 add MoreData datetime default getdate()
GO

select * from Foo
select * from synFoo
select * from vFooDelim
select * from vFooStar
GO
```

(don’t forget to)

```
--  Clean things up
DROP Synonym synFoo
DROP VIEW vFooDelim
DROP VIEW vFooStar
DROP TABLE Foo
```

A significantly more obscure situation (that we do all the time here), if you have to set up a reference in a database to an object in another database, you don’t necessarily know what columns are in that table (dynamic denormalized) are or will be, and you don’t know the name of the database at the time you write your code (one database per client, but only once they sign the contract) (usually), using synonyms can be a godsend. At the time of database creation, just dynamicaly build and run `CREATE SYNONYM myTable FOR <DatabaseName>.<schema>.MyTable`, and you are done—no matter what columns get added for which client in the future.

Comment: +1 for mentioning references to other databases. It is especially important when naming the referenced database after preferences or policies and not having to guess what an application assumes its name is.

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms are useful for situations where you're working with lots of disparate data sources/multiple databases etc, or doing data migrations.

I've never really found cause to use them in new, greenfield developments.